Do you need to redeploy after changing Amplify Environment Variables/Secrets?
Do they apply immediately to your hosted site (if so, is there an approximate time lag), or do you need to redeploy the site for the updated variables to take effect?
In my case I am working on a stripe webhook using the 'environment variables' section for the publishable key and the 'secrets' section for the stripe secret key, which I assume is the correct way to do so.
Current answers from AI contradict themselves and I cannot see in the docs where it is stated.
